# Y a-t-il un accent breton, et quelles sont ses particularités ?

Tags: accents-régionaux

J'habite et j'ai grandi en Bourgogne et, par le hasard des rencontres, j'ai dans mes connaissances pas mal de Bretons (nés en Bretagne, souvent de parents Bretons) qui vivent en Bourgogne.

Mais j'ai réalisé au détour d'une conversation que je ne pouvais savoir qu'une de mes connaissances était Bretonne, seulement après que celle-ci m'ait informée de son origine.

Contrairement aux accents du Sud et du Nord, ou de l'accent alsacien, qui sont souvent assez marqués et reconnaissables, je n'ai aucune connaissance sur l'existence d'un accent typiquement breton.

**Existe-t-il un accent breton? Et s'il existe, quels sont ses particularités?**

Je dois avouer que ma recherche se borne a mon expérience personnelle et au début de cette vidéo Youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UyzePIL9AI

où l'auteur se moque de l'accent parisien en parlant avec l'accent breton mais je ne suis pas convaincu: il semble plutôt s'agir de sociolectes, accent parisien stéréotypiquement "bourgeois" vs accent breton "populaire". Je connais pas mal de Bourguignons qui parlent exactement comme l'auteur de la vidéo.

Comment: Il est un fait que je ne m'explique mal : Je n'ai, moi non plus, jamais noté d'accent particulier pour les Bretons... **quand ils parlent français** en revanche... **quand ils parlent breton**, les différences d'accent, de prononciation, sont notables entre le Léon, le Trégor, la Cornouaille et le pays Vannetais.

Comment: Les Bretons ont un accent très prononcé, mais comme il est très proche de celui, très caractéristique aussi, généralement utilisé à la télévision, la radio, au cinéma qui uniformise rapidement la prononciation du français en France, il passe totalement inaperçu. ;-)

Comment: Comme quoi... *Gast!* à Dijon, tu ne saura pas dire si ton interlocuteur est un Breton ou un *Paour kaezh den* de la RTF... en revanche... à Bres' *Gast!*, tu sauras immanquablement s'il est maraîcher à Saint-Pol ou pêcheur à Douarnenez à la façon dont ils *baragouinent* (au sens de Ménage). ... ;-)

Comment: Ouais, c'est facile de se moquer des parisiens snobs à la con, mais tout le monde parle comme ce type.  Même pas capable de faire un bon accent toulousain, remarquons au passage, et là il y en a vraiment un.  (signé:  tête de chien)

Answer (score 5):

Comme indiqué par @aCOSwt, il est assez difficile de différencier un accent breton lorsque ceux-ci parlent français. 
Le français de l'axe Brest-Tours-Paris est souvent considéré comme le plus "basique" ou "sans accent" possible. Bien qu'en tant que nantais, on m'a parfois dit que certaines expressions que j'employais, ou certaines manières de prononcer mes syllabes étaient un peu singulières.

Néanmoins, lorsqu'ils parlent breton, il est très facile de deviner leur origine. Cela est principalement dû aux différences de dialecte dans les 8 pays bretons : le nantais, le rennais, le vannetais, le pays de St-Malo et une partie du pays de St-Brieuc parle historiquement le Gallo, alors que les autres pays de la "basse-Bretagne" parlent le breton.

De surcroît, l'enseignement du breton est récent : les écoles Diwan datent de 1973 ! Le breton enseigné à Nantes ou Rennes est donc nécessairement assez moderne, académique, et donc remarquable.

N'étant pas linguiste de formation, je ne me prononcerais pas sur la formation des accents en "Basse-Bretagne", mais le fait est qu'un léonnais est immédiatement reconnu par les cornouaillais (du moins parmi les bretonnants).

Answer (score 3):

Oui il y a un accent breton plus ou moins prononcé selon les gens, et surtout en basse Bretagne, soit à l'ouest de l'axe lorient-st brieuc. À rennes il est effectivement inexistant. C'est un accent qui a vraiment ses particularités issues du breton. Il est sans doute devenu moins fort et plus gommable chez les jeunes. Vous pouvez peut-être trouver des vidéos d'interviews de marin pêcheurs, ou d'anciens, ou mieux, aller dans un bar-pmu de la région pour decouvrir cet accent à son paroxysme.
Pour ta vidéo, c'est bien clairement un accent de brest (un peu exagéré), qui est particulier car c'était la seule enclave française en Finistère dû à la Marine nationale, ce qui le fait  avoir pas mal d'argot français..

Comment: Super reponse! Bienvenu sur le site. Si tu pouvais ajouter un lien vers une video (Youtube par exemple), ce serait genial.